# can't load assembly with typeof(UserType).AssemblyQualifiedName

Tags: c#, assemblies

I created a class `Address` in an Assembly `MyUserType.dll`. I want to load it in a console application. I tried the code below， but it failed:

```
 //cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Address).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

But when i try to use one of the other load assembly methods, it succeeds.

```
cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Address)));
cfg.AddAssembly("MyUserType");
```

The failed msg is:

> Message = "Could not load file or assembly 'Ordering.Data.Address, Ordering.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"

Why?

Comment: The first one uses a string as the argument, the second uses an Assembly as the argument.  Hard to guess what the overloads for AddAssembly() might look like.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Ordering.Data.Address` has a reference to an assembly not located in the same directory as the library, `MyUserType.dll`. Ensure that all referenced assemblies are in the System32 folder, the GAC or the same directory as the library.

Answer (score 0):

Type.AssemblyQualifiedName returns the qualified name for the type, as in it returns the FullName of the type concatenated with the FullName of the containing assembly. You seem to be passing that into Assembly.Load or similar so it obviously fails as that is not a valid assembly name.

To use AssemblyQualifiedName you need to pass it to something like the static [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method which will parse it correctly.